# How do I set up an old Ruby on Rails project on a new server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

I'm not a RoR programmer myself, but a good client of ours has sent a project their previous web team built and I need to get it up and running on their server.

The server uses cPanel and Ruby on Rails is already installed. I've created a project via the cPanel wizard and located the file tree via SSH.

Using SSH, I've tried to replace this file tree with the project I've been sent, but when I hit 'run' in cPanel, the application doesn't actually start (although the success message would indicate that it has).

If I leave the original cPanel-created application in place, I can run/stop no problem and the web interface at :12001 opens up just fine.

I assume there are either conflicts with RoR versions that I need to resolve, or there's simply more to it than just replacing the file tree? Again I'm not a RoR programmer and I'm having a hard time finding a migration guide that tells me anything other than "set up in cPanel and replace the files".

I'd very much appreciate either some genuinely useful links to RoR application setup/migration guides (ideally for cPanel) or a step-by-step answer please.

Comment: What does "the application doesn't actually start" mean? What errors are there in your logs?

Comment: Have you installed any gems/dependencies?

Comment: I haven't installed anything myself, no. I've no idea how to tell what plugins an application uses though so it's possible this application needs something I don't have. How would I find that out?

By "doesn't start", I mean cPanel gives the message "application started" but shows the status of "not running".

Answer (score 1):

First, forget Cpanel for now. Try in one environment where you can control everything.
Try to know better the rails version used and the associated gem19s or plugin if from 2.x days. The ruby version is important too, only then you can start defining a plan.

I'm afraid you won't get a step-by-step answer, but I'm sure you can be pointed in the right direction by providing the requested information.

Simple questions: Do you have a Gemfile file at the top at your project? Do you have any plugins (stuff in vendor/plugins)?

Update:

With the Gemfile provided here are the required steps:

1. Install ruby (if you haven't install it using [rvm](https://rvm.io/rvm/install). The version 1.9.3-x should be the safest.
2. Install [rubygems](https://rvm.io/rubies/rubygems)
3. Install [bundler](http://bundler.io/)
4. Go the project dir and run bundle install
5. run rake db:migrate (assure you have the database setup acording to config/database.yml
6. run rails s and check the logs and see if the server is up.

If after installing bundler, you don't have the `bundle` command in your path, you need to add this your `.bash_profile`:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin
export PATH
```

Comment: I have SSH access to this server but this is a completely new system to me - I've no idea where to begin.

How do I determine the version used for this application and it's requirements?

I do have a Gemfile - I'll pastebin the contents as soon as their service comes back online...

Comment: Thanks Paulo. I'm a little lost though!

The server isn't managed by us but I do have SSH and cPanel access.

# ruby --version
ruby 1.8.7

Rubygems and Ruby on Rails are in cPanel - I can't seem to find Bundler though. Do I 'just' need to manually install via Rubygems the plugins references by that gemfile?

Comment: Hmm, I did a 'gem install bundler' but the bundle command still doesn't exist?

Comment: @Ric I've updated the answer with the information you need. Check your $HOME/bin if there's a bundle file. This path may change in your system.

Comment: Thanks Paulo. It looks like I don't have enough access to see the binary - it's not in /bin and $HOME doesn't contain a bin tree or a .local. Also I can't slocate/locate for it. http://pastebin.com/sgBYbppq - I've asked the server guys to find where it's hiding and add to $PATH so that I can continue with this.

Comment: we found a bundle binary in $HOME/ruby/gems/bin/bundle but it's giving errors? http://pastebin.com/CfDqbe55

Comment: After a lot of messing about, I think what's happening is that even though ~/ruby/gems/bin/ is in my $PATH, the dependancies of bundler are trying to check that it's installed and failing because their $PATH doesn't contain the same reference. Is this possible?

Comment: @Ric Yes, it's possible. You seem to be using a shared host, so you need to check how to host Rails applications, because they are a lot different than for instance PHP applications. That's why I suggested an environment where you can control everything, try it there and later move to your shared host.